# A (Mostly) True Violet Pigment

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy

Is there a "True Violet" dye or object? That is, one that reflects higher frequency light than blue, but doesn't reflect red light? All the chemical dyes I have found were part violet, part purple when you looked at their reflective spectrum.

I think it would be interesting to show a demo in which you illuminate this object and switch between a low-cli white light, maybe incandescent; and a light with violet in its spectrum.

I could maybe get a Rugate filter, but I doubt it will be cheap, and I don't want to mess with hf making it myself.

Comment: Thin films can be designed to do this.